# strange error python code for definite integral of a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, integral

I am trying to compute a definite integral of a 2*10 matrix. I need to compute its definite integral from zero to t as we know the results must coincide to the sinus table.

Here is the code before reaching the goal gives error. The error probably is for the last lines.

I would be so thankful if you guide me please.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate
from scipy.integrate import quad 
from numpy import linalg as LA
from numpy.linalg import matrix_power
from scipy import linalg
from sympy import *
import scipy.integrate as it
from numpy import vectorize

############

from numba import vectorize, float64
##############################
# Constants
tmax = 20
t = np.arange(0.0, tmax, 1)
t0=0
m=len(t)
#print(t)
etest=np.matrix([[np.sqrt(0),np.sqrt(1),np.sqrt(2) ,np.sqrt(3),np.sqrt(4),np.sqrt(5),np.sqrt(6),np.sqrt(7),np.sqrt(8),np.sqrt(9)],
             [np.sqrt(10),np.sqrt(11),np.sqrt(12), np.sqrt(13),np.sqrt(14),np.sqrt(15),np.sqrt(16),np.sqrt(17),np.sqrt(18),np.sqrt (19)]])
pow = np.power( etest, 2 )
pow0=pow[0]
pow1=pow[1]

def norm2etest(xx):
       sum= pow0+pow1
       return sum
ans2=norm2etest(etest)
print(ans2)

def outerfun(norm2etest):
    return np.cos(norm2etest)

def integrandtest(xx):
    return outerfun(norm2etest(xx))
ttt=outerfun(norm2etest(etest))
#print(ttt)

for tnow in np.arange(0.0, tmax, 1):
 numnow=1*tnow
 num=np.array(numnow,dtype=int)
@np.vectorize
def integratetest(i):
    def integrandtest(t):
        return outerfun(norm2etest(t))[i]
    I, ff = quad(integrandtest, t0,tnow)
    return I
###########################
INTERVALtest=np.arange(0,10)
ANS1=integratetest(INTERVALtest)
print(INTERVALtest)
#print(ANS1.size)
```

gives this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\44integral.py", line 58, in <module>
    ANS1=integratetest(INTERVALtest)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2163, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2241, in _vectorize_call
    ufunc, otypes = self._get_ufunc_and_otypes(func=func, args=args)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2201, in _get_ufunc_and_otypes
    outputs = func(*inputs)
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\44integral.py", line 54, in integratetest
    I, ff = quad(integrandtest, t0,tnow)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 352, in quad
    points)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 463, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: One of the arguments is an array, when it should be a scalar (or at least a single element array).  I'd have to spend more time looking at the code, but my first guess is the bounds of this integral.  Get rid of that `np.vectorize` decorator, and do a simple python iteration on `t`.  It does not help with speed (READ THE DOCS), and can cause errors.

Comment: Thnx for your reply. Yes, it works in one code and it does not work here. How can I  form another iteration on t? do u have any idea or example that considers the integral as a vector?

Comment: quad integrates a scalar value

Comment: So for integrating an array which command is more approporiate?

Comment: In fact, I supposed that this would integrate each component of that array this each time is a fixed number. But the error is exactly about this so if there is a command that take integral of the whole array